# jQuery not detect click with script added to own WordPress theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm building my first WordPress theme and I have added my own script along with jQuery according to the info from WordPress.org codex pages, but nothing happens and I can't find the reason despite hours of searching! I'm stuck and going nowhere with this problem and need some help.

Both the script and jQuery are in the header when I right click to view the code. Have I missed something?

The code in the functions.php file:

```
function add_scripts()
{
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
```

The script that is really simple right now. Just for testing:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

     $('document').ready(function() {

    //Mobile menu
    $("#main-menu-mobile-btn").click(function(){
        alert("working!?");
    $("#main-menu-mobile").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
});
```

And this is the HTML-code that I have added to the header.php file:

```
<div id="main-menu-mobile-btn">test</div>
```

Comment: Does the test case work or do both not work?  Is there some html to prove that what you are selecting is there?  Additionally is jQuery loaded yet?

Comment: Why have you nested the `(document).ready()` method inside another `(document).ready()`?

Comment: The 1st script is php so shouldn't be getting passed to the html, check your php tags

Comment: Try with `$("#main-menu-mobile-btn").on('click', function(){...})` .And why have you done nested document load?

Comment: @kidA I followed instructions from the codex page about jQuery noConflict Wrappers http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `$` with `jQuery` and removing nested `.ready()` method.

Like this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

     //Mobile menu
     jQuery("#main-menu-mobile-btn").click(function(){
        alert("working!?");
        jQuery("#main-menu-mobile").slideToggle("fast");
     });
});
```

Comment: It's working!! But why is it working with jQuery instead of the $ sign? So I can't use the dollar sign at all then?

Comment: @3D-kreativ You have 2 ready functions, Remove $('document').ready(function() { from your file. And also remove one });

Comment: As I know it's good if you use `jQuery` instead of `$` in your WordPress sites.  but you can use `$` sign if you write it like this.  `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});`